# Vertical help lines only in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following tiKz code gives you a 100x10 grid of help lines.

```
\draw [help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid(100,10);
```

What is the code if you just want the 100 vertical helplines but not the 10 horizontal ones?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ystep` to fix the number of horizontal lines. For example, if you use `ystep=10` with a `10 X 10` grid:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines, dashed,ystep=10] (0,0) grid(10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

And there is always brute force:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,9}{
  \draw [help lines, dashed] (\x,0) -- (\x,10);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the first answer, you can hide the bottom horizontal line but not the top with the code:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [help lines, dashed,ystep=10] (0,1) grid(10,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}

The second answer works.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 3.1 of TikZ you can use `ystep=0` (or negative) to skip the vertical lines. And same for the horizontal lines with `xstep=0`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid[ystep=0] (10,10);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation in manual 3.1 does not mention this. Where can I find documentation on this subject?

Comment: @AndréC check the `xstep` key on page 157.

Comment: Thank you, where can you find this modification in the changelog or on the TikZ repository?

Comment: You reported a bug, it can be said that this is a new feature given your current answer.

Comment: @AndréC exactly, this is not a bug but a [feature ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/484/).

Comment: It is referenced as a **bug closed-fixed**  [484 Better grid operation](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/search/?q=status%3Aclosed-wont-fix+or+status%3Aclosed-accepted+or+status%3Aclosed-rejected+or+status%3Aclosed-duplicate+or+status%3Aclosed-works-for-me+or+status%3Aclosed+or+status%3Aclosed-invalid+or+status%3Aclosed-fixed)

Comment: @AndréC well the "bug" was the "bad" behavior of TikZ for zero or negative steps (I use quotation marks because this is subjective). And the final coordinate was not set as expected.